# Power BI Combine Value Plus Unichar In a Tabular Report

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have one tabular report to track the performance according to the month... if the difference is in positive values then need to show "GREEN UP ARROW" icon and if the difference is in negative values then need to show it in "RED DOWN ARROW".

**Required the above output into one single column not in to multiple column like in the below screenshot**

`I have tried the UP and Down Arrows in my report but I am unable to get the result in to one column.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting to achieve this. Edit `Cell Elements` on your visual, turn on `Icons` for the required series, then set the icon options as follows:

[image]

This displays as:

[image]